# Parse through the line in csv with python

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to parse csv file with python. When I try to read through each character in the string at each line, it only evaluate and prints out the result for the end character. I'm not sure what happened. Below is the code. Thanks.

```py
def assignment(s):
    switcher = {
        "N": "N",
        "N": "Q",
        "I" : "S", 
        "I" : "T",
        "I" : "K",
        "I" : "R", 
        "I" : "H",
        "I" : "D",
        "I" : "E"      
    }
    return switcher.get(s, "H")

with open('sentence.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_read = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for line in csv_read:
        i = 0
        index = 0
        aa = ""
        a = ""
        for index in range (len(line)):
            a=assignment(line[index])
            aa = aa + a
            print(aa)
            index +=1
            print(index)
        h = aa.count("H");
        i = aa.count("I");
        n = aa.count("N");

        print(aa + " has" + "H= " + str(h) + "I=" + str(i) + "N=" + str(n))
        ++i
```

Comment: print your dictionary - you can not have the same key multiple times. Your dict is equal to `{"N":"Q", "I":"E"}` - and I have no clue what you are trying to accomplish here - you might want to [ask] better.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: suppose dictionaries could even contain duplicate keys, how would it know which one to retrieve when you call `get` on it

Comment: concattenating strings is awful - they are immuteable and created + destroyed. Use lists instead and `a_string = ''.join(yourList)`afterwards.

Comment: I'm trying to switch multiple cases into one value. I didn't realize the dictionary switch case isn't going to work.

Comment: "dictionary switch case"?  I recommend that you work through a tutorial on dicts; you seem to have some incorrect assumptions about their use and/or functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your translation table (the dict) backwards.  You're trying to classify input characters as type `N`, `I`, or `H`.

I've reversed the dict order so you can look up things correctly, although you can do better if you search for Python translation tables.  I also reduced your code just enough to hard-code a test case:

```
def assignment(s):
    switcher = {
        "N": "N",
        "Q": "N",
        "S": "I",  
        "T": "I",
        "K": "I",
        "R": "I",  
        "H": "I",
        "D": "I",
        "E": "I"       
    }
    return switcher.get(s, "H")

csv_read = ["QWERTASDFGZXCVBYUIOPHJKLNM"]
for line in csv_read:
    i = 0 
    index = 0 
    aa = ""
    a = ""
    for index in range (len(line)):
        a=assignment(line[index])
        aa = aa + a 
        print(aa)
        index +=1 
        print(index)
    h = aa.count("H");
    i = aa.count("I");
    n = aa.count("N");

    print(aa + " has" + "H= " + str(h) + "I=" + str(i) + "N=" + str(n))
```

Output (last lines only):

```
25
NHIIIHIIHHHHHHHHHHHHIHIHNH
26
NHIIIHIIHHHHHHHHHHHHIHIHNH hasH= 17I=7N=2
```

I'll let you clean up the tracing and formatting from here.